# How to check if a input field has a value in the controller using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite simply trying to find out how I can retrieve the scopes information to see if it has a value or not in the controller.

I need to be able to write an if statement that says if this text input field is filled do this... if else do something different.

```
<form name="deadlineForm">
    <div class="app-select-date">
        <label for="deadline">Select deadline:</label>
        <input pickadate ng-model="deadline" format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select deadline"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

What is the best way about writing this code in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it bound to a variable (`deadline`) using `ng-model="deadline"`.

Your check in the controller becomes as simple as:

```
if ($scope.deadline != null && $scope.deadline != "") {
    //do something
}
```

or this can be even simplified to

```
if ($scope.deadline) {
    //do something
}
```

Simple [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16381/).

Comment: If you add a fiddle I'll push it through as the correct answer. :)

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.$watch('val', function (now, old) {
      if (now) {
        $scope.result = 'there is something';
      } else {
        $scope.result = 'there is nothing';
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <input type="text" ng-model="val">  
  <span ng-bind='result'>
</div>
```

Comment: Using $watch is a costly operation and from my point of view it should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: You seem to be right .. I think so .. but if there is another way to trigger code on the javascript side without using it I like to hear it as well :D

Answer (score 1):

You will get the value in the input as,

```
$scope.deadline
```

you can check as ,

```
if($scope.deadline) {  //or whatever condition you have to check null or empty
   //anything you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As from what I understand here it is:

```
<form name="deadlineForm">
    <div class="app-select-date" ng-if="deadline && deadline != ''">
        <label for="deadline">Select deadline:</label>
        <input pickadate ng-model="deadline" format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select deadline"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!deadline && deadline == ''">do something else</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check working example : [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pxxEIxFutywDX8BAT6qP?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<p>Data {{deadline}}!</p>
<div ng-if="deadline">There is date</div>
<div ng-if="!deadline">There is no date</div>

Only for testing
<button ng-click="makeDateEmpty()">Empty data</button>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deadline = '02/02/2002';
    //For testing only
    $scope.makeDateEmpty = function () {
           $scope.deadline = "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-model automatically binds any value entered into the input to a $scope variable of the same name.

This variable becomes available to plain JavaScript within your controller when you inject a dependency upon scope into it.

So `$scope.deadline` will give the current value of text entered into that input.

How you check that value depends on the context of *when* you'd like to check it.

If you're in an existing function, such as a function checking field validation upon form submission, a simple

```
if ($scope.deadline) {
   // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

would suffice.

If you're looking to trigger your logic the moment that input field changes, in the controller you could use the $watch directive, as [Konpat Ta Preechakul suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988446/664342), or you could add an ng-change or ng-blur attribute to your input, and call a controller-side function:

```
<input pickadate ng-model="deadline" format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select deadline" ng-change="selectedDate()"/>
```

and

```
$scope.selectedDate = function(){
    if ($scope.deadline) {
       // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
}
```

If you want conditional logic to occur directly in the view, bound real-time to values in the input field, then `ng-if`, `ng-show`, and `ng-hide` can be helpful:

```
<span ng-show="deadline">Show this if deadline has a value</span>
<span ng-hide="deadline">Don't show this if deadline has a value</span>
<span ng-if="!deadline">Don't render this into the DOM at all if deadline doesn't have a value</span>
```